# How to Add contributors to published Sitecore marketplace module

Tags: sitecore-marketplace

[image]

I have published a module in Sitecore marketplace. But now I can't add contributors or edit some of the text notes for the module.

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not confident, but I know in the past I have contacted Sitecore to assist with specific changes on the Marketplace. This might be one of them.

Answer (score 3):

To update the text next to the **Documentation** link, you need to edit the **Title** field just under it. See this screen shot for an example. Probably best not to use markup in that field:

[image]

I'll have to leave adding another contributor to someone else as I couldn't see how to do that either!

Answer (score 2):

Richard already answered the part about the content. I don't think you can add contributors yourself. You should contact Sitecore for that (there is a mail-address at the feedback link in the marketplace footer).

Answer (score 2):

Send me an email with the module name, and the name/email of the contributor and I can add them.

Comment: I sent you the information on https://sitecorechat.slack.com Thanks in Advance